# JavaFx ONLY TOP innerShadow

Tags: css, javafx

I'm playing with inner shadow fx effect. I'm trying to get shadow appearing only on top of VBox. Can anybody give me a hint

```
-fx-effect: innershadow(gaussian, #787878, 10, 0, 0,2 );
```

Comment: What is the issue with the CSS in your question?  Why is it not sufficient?

Comment: I'm getting inner shadow from all borders... I just want to have inner shadow on to of the box

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem similiar to yours. I wanted to add a shadow on every edges without the top. Look into my post: [JavaFX: Style undecorated Window with InnerShadow but without top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529906/javafx-style-undecorated-window-with-innershadow-but-without-top)

There you can find the solution given by Kalaschni: You can rebuild your shadow and add it to the border. In your case it looks like:

```
-fx-border-color: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), transparent);
-fx-border-style: solid;
-fx-border-width:
    5px 0 0 0;
```

Instead of px you may use em, too (-fx-border-width: 0.417em 0 0 0;).