# JavaFX: Style undecorated Window with InnerShadow but without top

Tags: css, javafx, window

I created an undecorated window with own title etc. For this one I added a style:

```
.pane-basicwindow{
-fx-border-color: gray; 
-fx-border-style: solid;    
-fx-border-width: 1;
-fx-effect: innershadow(three-pass-box, rgba(100, 100, 100, 1), 10, 0, 0, 0);}
```

With the help of this I created an innershadow. But I want to have the innershadow just on left, right and bottom side. Consequently the top side should be without shadow. I know that if I change the last value of the innershadow, I can move the position of the shadow upwards. For example like this

```
-fx-effect: innershadow(three-pass-box, rgba(100, 100, 100, 1), 10, 0, 0, -4);
```

But in this case the shadow on bottom side also moves upwards so that this one is bigger than the one one right/left side.

So my question is: What have to be done so that the shadows on left, right and bottom side have the same size while the innershadow on top is invisible? 
I checked a lot of other questions here but couldn't find an answer for my case. I also played a little bit with outsets but couldn't find a result, too. Does anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "simply" rebuild the shadow and just add it to the borders you like, something like this:

```
.pane-basicwindow {
    -fx-border-color:
        linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), transparent),
        linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), transparent),
        linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), transparent);
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-width:
        0 0 0 0.417em,
        0 0 0.417em 0,
        0 0.417em 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine :) But instead of em I used px for the border-width, because I got the error that the units don't match. But no everything is fine